# element <xs:choice> is not allowed at this location

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to define an XSD to an XML file, but I don't know why it doesn't work for me.
I have 2 files the XML one et the XSD one.

> here's my XML code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<article href="http://www.ensa-agadir.ac.ma/arti234" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="C:\Users\Mehdi\Desktop\XMLDS~1\DS1-EX1.xsd">
<titre>application de web sémantique</titre>
<nombrePages>12</nombrePages>
<auteur rond="principale">
    <nom>Hassani</nom>
    <prénom>Jamal</prénom>
    <établissement>Ensa-Agadir</établissement>
</auteur>
<auteur rond="secondaire">
    <nom>Karoum</nom>
    <prénom>Ahmed</prénom>
    <établissement>Ensa-Agadir</établissement>
</auteur>
<auteur rond="secondaire">
    <nom>Roumi</nom>
    <prénom>Jack</prénom>
    <établissement>Ensa-Rouen</établissement>
</auteur>
<résume>Il s'agit d'expliquer comment utiliser et appliquer le web sémantique dans le domaine informatique</résume>
```

> and my schema code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<xs:element name="article" type="articleT" />

<xs:complexType name="articleT">
    <xs:sequence maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:element name="titre" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="nombrePages" type="nbpagesT" />
    </xs:sequence>

    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="auteur" type="auteurT" />
    </xs:choice>

</xs:complexType>

<xs:simpleType name="nbpagesT">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="[1-9]+" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

But I don't know why do I have this error : 
[image]

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can only be one content of element - you need to choose between sequence, choice, all etc. However, these contents can be composed - your sequence can contain choices and so on. Plus, I am not sure with your usage of "choice" - this is used when you want to give XML few options of content. So having only one element "auteurT" doesn't make much sense. For example, XSD:

```
<xs:complexType name="phoneT">
  <xs:choice>
    <xs:element name="hardwire" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="mobile" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

If you assign "phoneT" type to an element, it can contain either element "hardwire" or "mobile".

Comment: Thank you a lot. I understand now, I should use sequence :-)

Comment: Attribute 'name' is not allowed in element <xs:complexType>

Answer (score 0):

A choice with only one element inside it is pointless (it doesn't even make that element optional). It's like Ford saying we offer a choice of colours, you can choose black.

If there was more than one choice you could write this:

```
<xs:complexType name="articleT">
    <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="titre" type="xs:string" />
       <xs:element name="nombrePages" type="nbpagesT" />
       <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="auteur" type="auteurT" />
          <xs:element name="rédacteur" type="rédacteurT" />
       </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

but I think the content model you actually want is:

```
<xs:complexType name="articleT">
    <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="titre" type="xs:string" />
       <xs:element name="nombrePages" type="nbpagesT" />
       <xs:element name="auteur" type="auteurT" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```